# Transformation of predictors

Tags: r

Here is link to data set :

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/YearPredictionMSD

The first column is the year; this is the target variable.

Below is my code :

```
data <- read.delim("YearPredictionMSD.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",")

# load packages
library(mlr)
library(dplyr)

# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# split the data into train and test sets
train_indices <- seq_len(463715)
test_indices <- seq(463716, nrow(data))
train_data <- data[train_indices, ]
test_data <- data[test_indices, ]
Year<- train_data[,1]

# define the possible transformations
transforms <- c("none", "log", "exp", "inv", "square", "sqrt", "center_scale", "range", "interval_binning", "quantile_binning")

# create a function to determine the best transformation for a predictor
determine_best_transform <- function(predictor, transforms, train_data, test_data) 
{
 rmse_values <- c()
 for (transform in transforms) {
   # apply the transformation to the predictor
   if (transform == "none") {
     transformed_predictor <- predictor
   } else if (transform == "log") {
     transformed_predictor <- log(predictor)
   } else if (transform == "exp") {
     transformed_predictor <- exp(predictor)
   } else if (transform == "inv") {
     transformed_predictor <- 1/predictor
   } else if (transform == "square") {
     transformed_predictor <- predictor^2
   } else if (transform == "sqrt") {
     transformed_predictor <- sqrt(predictor)
   } else if (transform == "center_scale") {
     transformed_predictor <- scale(predictor)
   } else if (transform == "range") {
     transformed_predictor <- scale(predictor, center = min(predictor), scale = max(predictor) - min(predictor))
   } else if (transform == "interval_binning") {
     transformed_predictor <- cut(predictor, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 10, 100, 1000, Inf), labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
   } else if (transform == "quantile_binning") {
     transformed_predictor <- cut(predictor, breaks = quantile(predictor), include.lowest = TRUE)
   }
   # train a linear regression model on the transformed predictor
   model <- lm(data = train_data, formula = Year ~ transformed_predictor)
   # make predictions on the test set
   predictions <- predict(model, newdata = test_data)
   # calculate the RMSE of the predictions
   rmse <- sqrt(mean((predictions - test_data$V1)^2))
   # store the RMSE value
   rmse_values <- c(rmse_values, rmse)
 }
 
 # determine the index of the transformation with the lowest RMSE
 best_transform_index <- which.min(rmse_values)
 # return the name of the best transformation
 return(transforms[best_transform_index])
}
best_transform_index

# apply the function to each predictor variable
transformations <- c()
for (i in 2:ncol(train_data)) {
 predictor <- train_data[, i]
 best_transform <- determine_best_transform(predictor, transforms, train_data, test_data)
 transformations <- c(transformations, best_transform)
}

# create a table of the predictor variables and their best transformations
transformations_table <- data.frame(Predictor = paste0("X", 1)

count the number of times each transformation was used
summary_table <- table(transformations)

print the transformations table
transformations_table

print the summary table
summary_table
```

My goal is to to modify the predictor variables to get the best model possible and also to make a summary table showing how many times each transform was used.

The part where ( # apply the function to each predictor variable ) is where I am having an error, I don't know what I did wrong in the codes.
I need assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of showing us the full code, it is nice to make a small focused example - give us a few rows/columns of data right before the error, and then just show us the code that causes the error. Also please include the error - error messages are often informative and helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: # apply the function to each predictor variable.                                                                   
This is the error I am having :         
                                                          
Warning: 'newdata' had 51630 rows but variables found have 463715 rows
Warning in predictions - test_data$V1 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
Warning in log(predictor) : NaNs produced
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

Comment: Thanks for posting the error message. Instead of showing us the full code, it is nice to make a small focused example - give us a few rows/columns of data right before the error, and then just show us the code that causes the error.